# Integrating $1/z$ over semi circle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I want to integrate $f(z)=1/z$ over both the semi circle in the upper half of the plane and the lower half of the plane. I parameterised the first as $\gamma(t)=e^{it}, 0\leq t\leq \pi$ and the second as $\gamma_2(t)=e^{it}, -\pi \leq t \leq 0.$

I know that one should give me $i\pi$ and the other should give $-i\pi$. However, I'm getting $i\pi $ from both of them. Why is this?

Comment: Does the contour for lower semicircle going clockwise? If yes, then your parametrization should be $\gamma_2(t) = e^{-it}, 0 \le t \le \pi$ instead.

Comment: @achillehui I was trying to parameterise both of them anticlockwise. Can I not do this?

Comment: a contour integral integrating over a curve along some direction. If you are going to transverse the contour clockwisely, then you need to use a parametrization that is clockwise. If you use a parametrization that is anticlockwise, you need to add an extra minus sign to the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In complex integration you need to be more clear with where your contours start and end; you have written $-\pi \le t \le 0$ but does this mean $t: 0 \to -\pi$ (clockwise from $z = +1$ to $z=-1$ via $-i$) or $t: -\pi \to 0$ (counterclockwise from $z = -1$ to $z = +1$ via $-i$).

Because $\int_a^b dx ~ f(x)  = -\int_b^a dx ~ f(x) $ these will give you opposite answers.

If you are indeed going counterclockwise for both, then notice that this **does** give you $2\pi i$ as it must (e.g. because of the Residue Theorem) and anyone who tells you otherwise is a dirty liar.

Comment: Thank you. So if were just computing the integral over the lower half of the plane from $-1$ to $1$, should I get $i \pi$ or $-i \pi$?

Comment: @user332597 What is $\int_{-\pi}^0 (e^{it} ~i~dt) / e^{it}$?

Comment: Is it just $i \pi$?

Comment: So if I tell you $z$ is $e^{it}$ what is $dz$ and what is $dz/z$?

Comment: Still just $i \pi?$

Comment: No. $dz$ is a differential variable and cannot be a macroscopic constant.Try again?

Comment: So $dz$ will be $ie^{it} \, dt$ and $dz/z = ie^{it} \, dt / e^{it}$?

Comment: Well, no, $dz/z$ will be $i ~dt.$ But after integrating that you do have $\big[i~t\big]_{-\pi \to 0}$ which we know is $(i 0) - (- i\pi).$ You might be skipping steps. In general I am not sure if you are getting this because you are reluctant to assert things.

Comment: OK, so the value of this integral is $i \pi$. But I also got $i \pi$ when I computed the integral over the upper half of the plane from $1$ to $-1$. Is it right that these both came out as $i \pi$?

Comment: Yes, $\big[i~t]_{-\pi\to\pi} = (i \pi) - (-i\pi) = 2 \pi i$ which is what it must be because that's what the residue theorem says that $\int_C dz/z$ must be for *any* closed contour that contains the point $z=0$, which trivially includes the counterclockwise circle that goes from $z=-1$ back to $z=-1$ via $-i, 0,$ and $+i$.